# Can't load data using Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm new to Redux and TS. I try to learn and practice Redux and TS writing a simple  react app. I have a file with data, I want my app to use Redux store. The problem is that I can't get data. I use AppContainer, where this data supposed to be as props. But I have an empty obj. So when I log state.clients.entries, I have nothing. Maybe there's a problem with my actions. Any help appreciated!
Here my code:

```js
export const CLIENTS_LOAD = 'CLIENTS_LOAD';

type ClientsLoadActions = {
    type: 'CLIENTS_LOAD';
}

export const clientsLoadActions = (): ClientsLoadActions => ({
    type: CLIENTS_LOAD,
});
```

```js
import {CLIENTS_LOAD} from '../actions/clients';


type InitialStateType = {
    entries: object;
    loading: boolean;
}

const initialState:InitialStateType = {
    entries: {},
    loading: false,
};

import {MockClients} from '../mocks/clients/index';

export const clientsReducer = (state = initialState, action: any) => {
  switch(action.type){
        case CLIENTS_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                entries: MockClients,
            };
    default:
        return state;
    }
   
};
```

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {App} from '../components/App/App';
import {clientsLoadActions} from '../actions/clients';
import {AppContainerComponentProps} from './AppContainer.interface';

class AppContainerClass extends React.Component<AppContainerComponentProps>{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.clientsLoadActions();
    }

    render(){
        const {clients} = this.props;
        return(
            <App clients={clients}/>
        );
    }
}




const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
    return {
        clientsLoadActions: () => dispatch(clientsLoadActions()),
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) =>{   
    const allClients = state.clients.entries;
    return {
        clients: allClients,
    };
}

export const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainerClass);
```

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {clientsReducer} from './clients';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    clients: clientsReducer,
});
```

Comment: On your reducer, you should be receiving the data as part of the action payload.

Comment: @aolivera, thanks for your answer! I tried6 but it didn't worked. I thought that if I need to get data from store(get request), I don't need action payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, when I declared entries as an array instead of object:

```js
const initialState:InitialStateType = {
    entries: [],
    loading: false,
};
```